# Plot a table of separate data below a ggplot2 graph that lines up on the X axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridextra

I'm looking to create a plot that contains a simple multi-line ggplot2 graph with a table of separate (but relevant) data below the graph that lines up by the X axis of the graph. The data table's column names do match the x axis of the graph (hours 1 to 24), but one column is dedicated to necessary row names.

Here are the graph and the data table separately:
[image: ggplot2 graph]

Data table is cut off at hour 16 for brevity, but does extend to 24. 
[image: Data Table]

I've been attempting different solutions in gridExtra all morning adjusting different parameters like nrow, ncol, heights and widths, but the most simple solution is only one that produces a somewhat reasonable result. The code and image below is the best I have achieved:

```
library(gridExtra)

p1 <- ggplot(load_forecast_plot, aes(group=Load_Type, y=Load_Values, x=Hour,  colour = Load_Type)) + 
  geom_line(size = 1) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(1:24))

p1 <- ggplotGrob(p1)

p2<-tableGrob(df)

grid.arrange(p1, p2, top = paste("Load and Weather Error Power Grid", Sys.Date()-1, sep = " "))

grid.draw(tableGrob(MISO_wx_PrevDay_error_test,theme=ttheme_minimal(base_size = 5)))
```

Which produces:
[image]

I would like the graph to be larger while the table is smaller and aligned along the x axis as much as possible. I've looked into examples where the table is converted to a ggplot2 object, but those examples have data that is the same in the plot and table unlike mine.

Below is my data for a reproducible example. Any help is much appreciated! Thank you.

data for the ggplot graph:

```
dput(load_forecast_plot)
structure(list(Hour = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 
5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 
11, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 14, 14, 14, 15, 15, 15, 16, 16, 16, 
17, 17, 17, 18, 18, 18, 19, 19, 19, 20, 20, 20, 21, 21, 21, 22, 
22, 22, 23, 23, 23, 24, 24, 24), Load_Type = c("Load", "DA_MTLF", 
"BC_MTLF", "Load", "DA_MTLF", "BC_MTLF", "Load", "DA_MTLF", "BC_MTLF", 
"Load", "DA_MTLF", "BC_MTLF", "Load", "DA_MTLF", "BC_MTLF", "Load", 
"DA_MTLF", "BC_MTLF", "Load", "DA_MTLF", "BC_MTLF", "Load", "DA_MTLF", 
"BC_MTLF", "Load", "DA_MTLF", "BC_MTLF", "Load", "DA_MTLF", "BC_MTLF", 
"Load", "DA_MTLF", "BC_MTLF", "Load", "DA_MTLF", "BC_MTLF", "Load", 
"DA_MTLF", "BC_MTLF", "Load", "DA_MTLF", "BC_MTLF", "Load", "DA_MTLF", 
"BC_MTLF", "Load", "DA_MTLF", "BC_MTLF", "Load", "DA_MTLF", "BC_MTLF", 
"Load", "DA_MTLF", "BC_MTLF", "Load", "DA_MTLF", "BC_MTLF", "Load", 
"DA_MTLF", "BC_MTLF", "Load", "DA_MTLF", "BC_MTLF", "Load", "DA_MTLF", 
"BC_MTLF", "Load", "DA_MTLF", "BC_MTLF", "Load", "DA_MTLF", "BC_MTLF"
), Load_Values = c(59141, 59260, 57862, 56493, 56470, 54964, 
54480, 54553, 52996, 53270, 53252, 51683, 53050, 52520, 50845, 
53020, 51723, 49627, 53844, 51907, 49293, 56956, 55069, 52700, 
60975, 60036, 58251, 65595, 65023, 63881, 69796, 69023, 68776, 
73392, 72517, 72591, 76412, 74896, 75452, 78454, 76538, 77547, 
79959, 77782, 79256, 81315, 78851, 80627, 82478, 79921, 81763, 
82638, 80027, 81896, 81244, 78906, 80328, 78484, 76627, 77304, 
77187, 75130, 75391, 74495, 72612, 72776, 69736, 68216, 68488, 
64844, 63756, 64145)), row.names = c(NA, -72L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

data table:

```
dput(df)
structure(list(WX_Error = c("CloudCover", "DewPoint", "RainFall", 
"SolarRadiation", "Temperature", "WindSpeed"), `1` = c("-13.72%", 
"-0.41°F", "0in", "0min", "-0.86°F", "0.26mph"), `2` = c("-8.52%", 
"-0.05°F", "-0.01in", "0min", "-1.2°F", "-0.11mph"), `3` = c("-9.22%", 
"-0.41°F", "-0.01in", "0min", "-1.26°F", "-1.41mph"), `4` = c("-14.57%", 
"-0.98°F", "-0.01in", "0min", "-1.48°F", "-0.99mph"), `5` = c("-15.81%", 
"-0.83°F", "-0.01in", "0min", "-0.83°F", "-1.58mph"), `6` = c("-13.43%", 
"-0.61°F", "0in", "-0.43min", "-0.46°F", "0.48mph"), `7` = c("-14.23%", 
"-0.28°F", "0in", "7.91min", "-1.15°F", "-0.43mph"), `8` = c("-2.29%", 
"0.1°F", "0in", "1.3min", "-0.72°F", "0.51mph"), `9` = c("-3.63%", 
"0.2°F", "0in", "1.96min", "-0.94°F", "-0.9mph"), `10` = c("4.73%", 
"0.25°F", "0in", "-2.99min", "-0.69°F", "0.25mph"), `11` = c("-8.68%", 
"0.8°F", "0.01in", "5.03min", "-0.83°F", "0.81mph"), `12` = c("-4.42%", 
"0.64°F", "0.01in", "2.34min", "-0.3°F", "0.9mph"), `13` = c("-15.06%", 
"0.49°F", "-0.01in", "8.08min", "0.29°F", "0.44mph"), `14` = c("-25.35%", 
"0.55°F", "-0.01in", "14.4min", "0.47°F", "0.59mph"), `15` = c("-19.36%", 
"0.6°F", "-0.01in", "10.76min", "0.44°F", "1.29mph"), `16` = c("-8.1%", 
"0.17°F", "-0.01in", "5.03min", "0.29°F", "1.26mph"), `17` = c("-21.01%", 
"-0.27°F", "-0.01in", "11.74min", "1.52°F", "0.72mph"), `18` = c("-22.84%", 
"-0.74°F", "-0.01in", "12.77min", "2.17°F", "1.34mph"), `19` = c("-18.57%", 
"-0.55°F", "0in", "10.35min", "0.46°F", "1.13mph"), `20` = c("-10.39%", 
"-0.91°F", "0.03in", "5.6min", "0.65°F", "0.71mph"), `21` = c("-6.65%", 
"-0.28°F", "0.06in", "1.66min", "-0.5°F", "-0.56mph"), `22` = c("-0.2%", 
"-0.4°F", "-0.01in", "0min", "-0.33°F", "-1.35mph"), `23` = c("4.39%", 
"0.11°F", "-0.01in", "0min", "-0.5°F", "-0.47mph"), `24` = c("-5.65%", 
"0.64°F", "0.01in", "0min", "-0.43°F", "0.35mph")), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), groups = structure(list(Date = structure(c(18407, 18407, 
18407, 18407, 18407, 18407), class = "Date"), wx_vars = c("CloudCover", 
"DewPoint", "RainFall", "SolarRadiation", "Temperature", "WindSpeed"
), .rows = list(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L)), row.names = c(NA, -6L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = FALSE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can format the table as a ggplot object and then use the patchwork package to take care of the alignment for you.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

p1 <- ggplot(load_forecast_plot, aes(group=Load_Type, y=Load_Values, x=Hour,  colour = Load_Type)) + 
  geom_line(size = 1) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(1:24))

p2 <- gridExtra::tableGrob(df)
# Set widths/heights to 'fill whatever space I have'
p2$widths <- unit(rep(1, ncol(p2)), "null")
p2$heights <- unit(rep(1, nrow(p2)), "null")

# Format table as plot
p3 <- ggplot() +
  annotation_custom(p2)

# Patchwork magic
p1 + p3 + plot_layout(ncol = 1)
```

[image]

I know it doesn't look great right now; you'd have to tinker with the device size and text size a bit more. But, the question was about the alignment and that seems OK.

EDIT:

You can match up the axis ticks with the columns too if you set the x-axis correctly:

```
p1 <- ggplot(load_forecast_plot, aes(group=Load_Type, y=Load_Values, x=Hour,  colour = Load_Type)) + 
  geom_line(size = 1) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(1:24),
                     limits = c(-1, 24),
                     expand = c(0,0.5))
```

or you could set the second column as axis text:

```
p1 <- ggplot(load_forecast_plot, aes(group=Load_Type, y=Load_Values, x=Hour,  colour = Load_Type)) + 
  geom_line(size = 1) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(1:24),
                     expand = c(0,0.5))

p2 <- gridExtra::tableGrob(df)[, -c(1:2)]
p2$widths <- unit(rep(1, ncol(p2)), "null")
p2$heights <- unit(rep(1, nrow(p2)), "null")

p3 <- ggplot() +
  annotation_custom(p2) +
  scale_y_discrete(breaks = rev(df$WX_Error), 
                   limits = c(rev(df$WX_Error), ""))

p1 + p3 + plot_layout(ncol = 1)
```

EDIT2:

I also didn't see any text size options, but here is how you could change the font size manually:

```
is_text <- vapply(p2$grobs, inherits, logical(1), "text")
p2$grobs[is_text] <- lapply(p2$grobs[is_text], function(text) {
  text$gp$fontsize <- 8
  text
})
```

Comment: I like the first example with the edit. I'm looking into text size as that might work! The second example throws an error: "Error in zero_range(from) : x must be length 1 or 2"

Comment: Hmm strange; I re-ran the code on a different machine with lower R version (3.6.3) and I don't get the error.

Comment: I found how to change text size in the table. In the tableGrob function, call: theme = ttheme_default(base_size = 6). base_size can be adjusted which I'm currently playing with. I marked your answer as correct and I think this edit will complete it. I really appreciate your help @teunbrand. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

After a bit of fiddling around I got to this:

```
library(ggpubr)
p1 <- ggplot(load_forecast_plot, aes(group=Load_Type, y=Load_Values, x=Hour,  colour = Load_Type)) + 
  geom_line(size = 1) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(1:24)) +
  theme(legend.position="top")+
  theme(plot.margin=unit(c(0,1,0,3.1),"cm"))
p1


p2 <- ggtexttable(df)

plot <- ggarrange(p1, p2,
                  ncol = 1, nrow = 2,
                  heights = c(10,3))
plot
```

Just play around with the margin and the device size until it is more or less aligned. Is a bit of a workaround though and @teunbrand's solution that I just saw now looks more promising.

[image]