# how to draw plot with legend and data as part of x-axis?

Tags: r

I recently saw a plot from a governmental report which provides a plot like this:

[image]

I am just wondering how to (or whether it is possible) directly draw this type of line plot(*Put the summary data table as part of x-axis*)in either R or SAS? Where I should find the related plot tutorial references? Thanks a lot~~!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have a nice example using `gridExtra::tableGrob`

[Create a plot with a table under the plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66200466/create-a-plot-with-a-table-under-the-plot)

You may work on it a bit to get what you're looking for.

Comment: Looks like the example plot was made by SAS, and perhaps used the statement XAXISTABLE.