# Can this Excel pivot chart be duplicated in ggplot?

Tags: r, excel, ggplot2, tidyr, pivot-chart

Is it possible to duplicate this Excel pivot chart with `ggplot2` or have something relatively similar? I really like that the chart displays the prices and the year-to-year percent changes on the legend below.
[image]

Here's the `dput()` output of my sample dataset:

```
price <- structure(list(selling_date = structure(c(17869, 17870, 17870, 
                                          17872, 17872, 17872, 17875, 17878, 17879, 17879, 17882, 17882, 
                                          17885, 17889, 17892, 17893, 17893, 17893, 17896, 18232, 18232, 
                                          18233, 18234, 18235, 18235, 18235, 18236, 18236, 18239, 18239, 
                                          18240, 18242, 18242, 18243, 18243, 18246, 18250, 18250, 18254, 
                                          18257, 18260, 18260, 18261, 18261, 18261, 18598, 18599, 18599, 
                                          18600, 18607, 18612, 18613, 18614, 18617, 18617, 18619, 18619, 
                                          18619, 18624, 18626, 18627, 18964, 18967, 18968, 18970, 18970, 
                                          18976, 18977, 18977, 18981, 18983, 18990), class = "Date"), selling_price = c(800000, 
                                                                                                                        625000, 105000, 580000, 419000, 360000, 795000, 320000, 790000, 
                                                                                                                        625000, 779450, 415000, 615000, 555000, 500000, 710000, 655000, 
                                                                                                                        600000, 639950, 680000, 280000, 365000, 730000, 581000, 360000, 
                                                                                                                        530000, 950000, 825000, 550000, 300000, 385000, 590000, 590000, 
                                                                                                                        660000, 410000, 510000, 799999, 575000, 690000, 700000, 565000, 
                                                                                                                        735000, 866250, 339000, 360000, 674900, 560000, 435000, 1485000, 
                                                                                                                        840000, 525000, 900000, 886000, 647000, 775000, 648000, 650000, 
                                                                                                                        349000, 675000, 1225000, 1260000, 585000, 1100000, 1400000, 960000, 
                                                                                                                        695000, 1000000, 1050000, 630000, 751000, 1225000, 1930721), 
               id_num = c(1364645, 1330850, 1385154, 1337665, 1349409, 1360807, 
                          1356805, 1389378, 1333399, 1286526, 1380444, 1371559, 1325930, 
                          1376221, 1386441, 1334435, 1333581, 1372726, 1364979, 1508940, 
                          1534939, 1526490, 1522480, 1504380, 1536453, 1538182, 1490032, 
                          1533847, 1504948, 1529791, 1521259, 1537746, 1538750, 1538455, 
                          1528390, 1526742, 1538271, 1512930, 1518796, 1517900, 1538821, 
                          1511886, 1544288, 1511768, 1535256, 1680111, 1683767, 1675425, 
                          1639303, 1680942, 1669765, 1683493, 1685799, 1637667, 1682404, 
                          1690692, 1677272, 1651257, 1687505, 1674430, 1601173, 1798143, 
                          1857616, 1850499, 1857149, 1840874, 1831562, 1843883, 1859947, 
                          1858923, 1856840, 1854640), year = c(2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 
                                                               2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 
                                                               2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 
                                                               2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 
                                                               2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 
                                                               2019, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 
                                                               2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2021, 2021, 2021, 
                                                               2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                               -72L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I'm only able to recreate a basic line plot with the same data in `ggplot2`, which is in the chart below.

[image]

The RStudio library I have loaded for this is `library(tidyverse)`. Getting average and median price is easy. Here's the code I'm using for that:

```
price_groups <- price %>% 
  group_by(year) %>% 
  summarize(avg_sp = mean(selling_price),
            med_sp = median(selling_price)
```

Getting the percent change year-to-year is in the code below. Unless there is another way, I've found I must create an object of my grouped summaries first before I can use the `lag()` or `lead()` functions on my groups.

```
price_groups <- price_groups %>% 
  mutate(lag_avg_sp = lag(avg_sp),
     avg_pct_change = (avg_sp - lag_avg_sp) / lag_avg_sp,
     lag_med_sp = lag(med_sp),
     med_pct_change = (med_sp - lag_med_sp) / lag_med_sp) %>% 
  select(-c(lag_avg_sp, lag_med_sp))
```

Here's the code I've used so far in `ggplot2`:

```
options(scipen = 999)

ggplot(price_groups, aes(x = year)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = avg_sp, color = "Avg SP"), size = 2) +
  geom_line(aes(y = med_sp, color = "Median SP"), size = 2) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 1100000, by = 250000),
                     limits = c(0, 1100000),
                     labels = scales::dollar_format()) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("Avg SP" = "steelblue", "Median SP" = "dark gray")) +
  labs(x = "Year",
       y = "Selling Price",
       color = "Price Type",
       title = "Annual Change in Price\n") +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom",
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

I don't know enough about `ggplot2` or the `tidyverse` functionality to duplicate this Excel chart or create something relatively similar. I'd like to display average and median price along with average and median percent changes in the legend on the bottom on the same plot. Is this possible?

I'd prefer not to display the numbers on the lines themselves (above or below) as I think it looks cluttered.

Also, the date in the Excel chart is in wide format rather than long. After creating the `price_groups` object, I tried messing with `pivot_wider()` to recreate the format, but I don't have enough experience with this feature to figure it out. Is there a way to make the variables `avg_sp`, `avg_pct_change`, `med_sp`, and `med_pct_change` row names with the years as column names and have the values be the prices and percentages?

If recreating the Excel pivot chart isn't possible, I'd be fine with an option using `pivot_wider()` to create a table and make a separate image I could append to the graph.

Comment: Related, do these answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62047359/plot-a-table-of-separate-data-below-a-ggplot2-graph-that-lines-up-on-the-x-axis  and
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41164675/adding-a-table-of-values-below-the-graph-in-ggplot2 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16680063/how-can-i-add-a-table-to-my-ggplot2-output

Comment: Close.... but I'm having the same problem sizing the table grob so that the years on the table align with the years on the plot.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a shot. It's not perfect, and I don't know how to align the years in the plot with the columns in the table ...

Several packages needed for this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr) # pivot_*
# library(gridExtra) # tableGrob
library(patchwork)
```

Data reshaping:

```r
price_summ <- price %>%
  mutate(year = format(selling_date, format = "%Y")) %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  summarize(
    "Avg SP" = mean(selling_price),
    "Median SP" = median(selling_price),
    .groups = "drop"
  ) %>%
  arrange(year) %>%
  mutate(
    across(
      `Avg SP`:`Median SP`,
      ~ c(NA, zoo::rollapplyr(., 2, FUN = function(z) diff(z) / z[1])),
      .names = "{sub('SP', '% Change', .col)}"
    )
  ) %>%
  pivot_longer(-year, names_to = "Price Type", values_to = "Selling Price")
price_summ
# # A tibble: 16 x 3
#    year  `Price Type`    `Selling Price`
#    <chr> <chr>                     <dbl>
#  1 2018  Avg SP             573074.     
#  2 2018  Median SP          615000      
#  3 2018  Avg % Change           NA      
#  4 2018  Median % Change        NA      
#  5 2019  Avg SP             574086.     
#  6 2019  Median SP          578000      
#  7 2019  Avg % Change            0.00177
#  8 2019  Median % Change        -0.0602 
#  9 2020  Avg SP             783431.     
# 10 2020  Median SP          674950      
# 11 2020  Avg % Change            0.365  
# 12 2020  Median % Change         0.168  
# 13 2021  Avg SP            1029702.     
# 14 2021  Median SP         1000000      
# 15 2021  Avg % Change            0.314  
# 16 2021  Median % Change         0.482
```

And two plot components (with a little more reshaping in `gg2`):

```r
gg1 <- dplyr::filter(price_summ, !grepl("%", `Price Type`)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(as.integer(year), `Selling Price`)) +
  geom_line(aes(group = `Price Type`, color = `Price Type`)) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::dollar_format()) +
  labs(x = NULL) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")

gg2 <- price_summ %>%
  mutate(
    value2 = case_when(
      is.na(`Selling Price`) ~ "",
      grepl("%", `Price Type`) ~ scales::percent(`Selling Price`, accuracy = 0.01),
      TRUE ~ scales::dollar(`Selling Price`)
    )
  ) %>%
  pivot_wider(`Price Type`, names_from = "year", values_from = "value2") %>%
  arrange(grepl("%", `Price Type`), `Price Type`) %>%
  rename(` ` = `Price Type`) %>%
  gridExtra::tableGrob(., rows = NULL)

gg1 / gg2
```

[image: ggplot2 line plot and table under it]

Comment: Hey, this is pretty good! I figured out a bit of the `tableGrob` part, but now I can't figure out how to make the years in the table align with the years in the plot. Are there table resizing options for the `tableGrob` function? The help section on it doesn't really explain much.

Comment: You might be able to play with how `patchwork` lays them out. It will be sensitive to resizing and such, but it is another avenue to research. I'm not a guru with `tableGrob` so unfortunately I cannot give much help beyond what is already here.