Add data table on x axis in ggplot in R?
I'm using R to make a combined barplot + line with ggplot2. I want to add a data table in the x axis just like it's possible to do in excel.
This is my data and the plot I managed to make:
graf4 <- data.frame(anoobito = c(2006:2023),
                    perc_mif = c(37.5, 40.9, 65.3, 76.4, 84.4, 85.0, 86.0, 89.1, 95.1, 92.6, 93.8, 95.8, 95.0, 94.6, 92.4, 91.6, 95.8, 98.0),
                    rmm = c(52.4, 69.5, 60.7, 72.3, 74.5, 69.8, 63.7, 75.5, 71.2, 74.0, 74.6, 82.9, 60.6, 81.0, 114.0, 156.0, 77.4, 70.3))

ggplot(data = graf4, aes(x = anoobito)) +
  geom_bar(aes(y = rmm, fill = "RMM"), stat = "identity", width = 0.8) +
  geom_line(aes(y = perc_mif * (160 / 100), color = "% Inv. MIF"), size = 1) +  # Color for line
  geom_text(aes(y = rmm, label = rmm), color = "white", vjust = 8, hjust = 0.5, size = 6) +  # Labels for rmm inside bars
  geom_text(aes(y = perc_mif * (160 / 100), label = perc_mif), color = "black", vjust = -0.5, size = 6) +  # Labels for perc_mif
  scale_y_continuous(
    expand = expansion(mult = c(0, 0.1)),
    name = "RMM/100.00 NV",
    limits = c(0, 160),
    breaks = seq(0, 160, by = 20),
    sec.axis = sec_axis(~ . * (100 / 160), name = "% investigação MIF", breaks = seq(0, 100, by = 10))
  ) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(2006, 2023, by = 1)) +
  scale_fill_manual(name = " ", values = "#375f8c") +  # Legend for bars
  scale_color_manual(name = " ", values = "#60cef2") +  # Legend for line
  labs(x = " ") +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 20) +
  theme(axis.line.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_text(colour = "black"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(colour = "black"),
        legend.position = "bottom",
        panel.grid = element_blank())

This is the desired output:


I'm curious if there's an extension package that helps with this. The two approaches I've seen are to either plot the text below the plot area and use coord_cartesian(clip = "off"), or else to use gt() to make a table and then align that with patchwork. Neither is as simple as the excel option, unfortunately.

For example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62047359/plot-a-table-of-separate-data-below-a-ggplot2-graph-that-lines-up-on-the-x-axis

As suggested by another post, you can use paste with sep="\n". Positioning the legend is a bit of trial and error, but should be possible using various legend. theme arguments.
ggplot(data = graf4, aes(x = anoobito)) +
  geom_bar(aes(y = rmm, fill = "RMM"), stat = "identity", width = 0.8) +
  geom_line(aes(y = perc_mif * (160 / 100), color = "% Inv. MIF"), size = 1) +
  scale_y_continuous(
    expand = expansion(mult = c(0, 0.1)),
    name = "RMM/100.00 NV",
    limits = c(0, 160),
    breaks = seq(0, 160, by = 20),
    sec.axis = sec_axis(~ . * (100 / 160), 
                        name = "% investigação MIF", 
                        breaks = seq(0, 100, by = 10))) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(2006, 2023, by = 1),
                     labels=~paste(., graf4$rmm,
                                      graf4$perc_mif,
                                      sep="\n")) +
  scale_fill_manual(name = "", values = "#375f8c") +  
  scale_color_manual(name = " ", values = "#60cef2") + 
  labs(x = " ") +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 10) + 
  theme(axis.line.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_text(colour = "black"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(colour = "black"),
        plot.margin=margin(c(0,1,0.5,1), unit="cm"),
        legend.position = "inside",
        legend.position.inside = c(-0.03, -0.06),
        legend.key.height= unit(1, "mm"),
        legend.margin = margin(c(-3,0,-2,0), unit="mm"),
        legend.spacing.y=unit(0, "mm"),
        panel.grid = element_blank())


